# Android: How to insert images into edit text

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am trying to create a blog type app, at the moment I am using an image button to get replaced with an image using the picasso libaray. Although, how would I go about adding/inserting image(s) from my gallery to an edit text. I am not sure how to go about doing this:

[image: Something like this]

Comment: that doesn't look like an image inside of an edit text... that looks like an image above a textview

Comment: Ahh I see! that makes sense lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the image isn't very clear in describing your question, you can however use the below code to add a drawable in EditText.

```
<EditText
...     
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/some_drawable"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>
```

Comment: According to your image, you don't have to use EditText with images. Simply use imageview and textview. If that is not what you meant, please update your question and the image. To add multiple images to an edittext you would have to use LayerDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `imageView.setCompountDrawablesWithInstrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)`

This way you can dynamically pass in the images you want to display from a gallery.